# Javascript insertAdjacentHTML not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

In fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/u3bmytnL/, does not work as expected

```
var x = document.createElement("button");
x.textContent = "byyyyy";
elx = document.getElementById("el");
elx.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', x);
```

Answer (score 9):

That's should resolve:

```
var x = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var text = document.createTextNode("byyyy");
x.appendChild(text);
elx = document.getElementById("el");
elx.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', x.outerHTML);
```

The [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML) needs a string as second parameter, and you was passing a DOM element, so you need to get the HTML string

Answer (score 1):

It is because `insertAdjacentHTML` method takes a string instead of an element node reference.

[MDN insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML)

Answer (score -1):

You should put a string as the second parameter